# Creating composite control with client feature

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to develop composite control where some of the work would be executed on client side. 
For that I am implementing IScriptControl.

ScriptReference points to a script file with client object.

Let's say I want it to have Listview(html select) control that onselect will run javascript function based on  the selected value.

I can't just create the control dynamically is client js, because the control has UI on design mode so I must create the select control on server side (I create it in override void Render)

My problem how and where to assign the onselect event for the selection.

**Update:**
Maybe I should add select's id as property to ScriptControlDescriptor, then in client control retrieve this id and attach the needed handler to the event?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Attributes collection of the object, you can add the `onselect` attribute you desire.  Just call `HtmlSelect.Attributes.Add("onselect", "functionYouWantToCall();");`

To clarify, if the HTML Select is being created during Render on the server side in C#, then the line above is used to register the onselect client side event to call the `functionYouWantToCall()` java script method.

There are many ways to add javascript functions to an ASP.NET page at runtime, or by including a static JS file.  For this look into the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx).

In an ASPX page or not, once added to a page, a control can access the Page property, which will give you access to the Page and therefore the ClientScript property.

Likewise, you can embed JS files in a DLL, and have them served by IIS automatically, using the [ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptresource.aspx) method.

Comment: and where  should I define functionYouWantToCall()?

Comment: I can't access the client object (ScriptReference ) directly from server side.

Comment: The problem is that this is not an aspx  page, it's a dll control

Comment: If your control is added to a page, you can access all of the Page's properties using the Page property of your control.  I edited my answer to reflect how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your control create the javascript and have the control register?
Here's the link I put in the comments.  It's called Injecting Client-Side Script from an ASP.NET Server Control
   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx

Comment: in the page load (or another event) of the control  - I've found this example of what you might want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx

Comment: this can work, but it's very ugly. i hope to get a better solution. Some thing that can use the Ajax ScriptControl

Answer (score 0):

A similar topic is discussed here ..try it out if you are interested
http://able2know.org/topic/2802-1